# Set jTextArea to visible false by default

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am making an application that show the information I entered in a textfield, combo box, etc.. into a text area.

I want to hide the text area when I started up the application and when I press on a button I want to show with the desired information.

I've tried to place `<nameOfTextArea>.setVisible(false);` in the frame constructor, but it is still visible.

How can I start up the frame without seeing this text area?

Constructor frame:

```
public StudentInfoFrame() {

    initComponents();

    textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo.setVisible(false);

}
```

My button in the frame:

```
private void uitvoerButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    try{
        ..... Variables here .....

        textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo.setVisible(true);
        textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo.append("Voornaam: \t\t" + voornaam + "\n"
                                       + "Achternaam: \t\t" + achternaam + "\n"
                                       + "E-mail adres: \t\t" + email + "\n"
                                       + "Geboortedatum: \t" + geboortedatum + "\n"
                                       + "Lengte: \t\t" + lengte + "m\n"
                                       + "Gewicht: \t\t" + gewicht + "kg\n"
                                       + "Geslacht: \t\t" + geslacht + "\n"
                                       + "Vooropleiding(en): \t" + vooropleiding + "\n"
                                       + "Uitwonend: \t\t" + uitwonend);

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code is not clear. what is hidden inside `initComponents()` method? Where are your adding `textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo`?

Comment: initComponents() is added by default when you make the frame. I did not add it to the constructor. The initComponents method adds all the labels, boxes etc. The textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo, the name of my textArea, is added on my frame with the drag and drop system from Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

My question is solved. The jTextArea was invisible, but the jScrollPane was not.

Made the jScrollPane invisible in the constructor and it worked as intended.

Thanks for the help from the people above this post.

Answer (score 0):

Call [JComponent#revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) on parent component after changing element's visibility.

Call `JFrame#setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo.hide();
```

or this:

```
textAreaVoorOpslaanInfo.show();
```